# Debugging a leetcode solution in javascript - coin change,

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, coin-change

I solved a leetcode question that looks correct to me, but It's not and I am unable to understand why it is wrong. Can someone please tell me why my solution is not working
Following is the question

> You are given an integer array coins representing coins of different denominations and an integer amount representing a total amount of money.Return the fewest number of coins that you need to make up that amount. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination of the coins, return -1.
> You may assume that you have an infinite number of each kind of coin.

Here is my solution

```
var coinChange = function (coins, amount) {
coins = coins.sort((a, b) => b - a)
let cache = {}
let result = coinChangeHelper(coins, amount, 0, cache)
console.log(cache)
return result
};

var coinChangeHelper = (coins, amount, coinUsedTillNow, cache) => {
    if (cache[amount] !== undefined) {
        return cache[amount]
}

if (amount === 0) {
    return coinUsedTillNow
}

if (amount < 0) {
    return -1
}

let result = Infinity
for (let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
    let temp = coinChangeHelper(coins, amount - coins[i], coinUsedTillNow + 1, cache)
    if(temp === -1)
        continue
    result = Math.min(result,temp)
}
if (result !== Infinity) {
    cache[amount] = result
    return result
}

cache[amount] = -1
return -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly when the correct course of action is always to use the highest-denomination coins first.

For example, if the denominations are `[10, 5, 2, 1]`, and the target amount is greater than `10`, I should always use the `10` coin at least once.

However, if the denominations are `[100, 57, 50, 1]`, and the target amount is `107`, then I should not be using the `100` coin. Your code will return `8`, but the correct answer is `2`.

The problem with your code, therefore, is that it is abandoning the search without trying all possible combinations (because of the `return` in your `for` loop). You should be comparing the results of different attempts, to find the one that requires the fewest coins.

Comment: I tried what you asked, but the solution is still not working, and it passed the test case you mentioned. Thanks for the improvement

it fails for the following test case - coins - [186,419,83,408] and amount = 6249. THe correct answer is supposed to be 20, but the code returns 26

Answer (score 0):

You are using greedy algorithm that works for some inputs only.

Apply dynamic programming:

```js
var coinChange = function (coins, amount) {
  let cache = {}
  cache[0] = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <= amount - coins[i]; j++) {
          if (cache[j] !== undefined) {
             if (cache[j+coins[i]] === undefined) {
                cache[j+coins[i]] = cache[j] + 1
             }
             else {
                cache[j+coins[i]] = Math.min(cache[j] + 1, cache[j+coins[i]])
             }
          }
      }
    }
   return cache[amount]
}
console.log(coinChange([2,5,7],12))
console.log(coinChange([2,5,7],13))
console.log(coinChange([2,5,7],14))
console.log(coinChange([2,5,7],15))
```

Comment: I know this solution. However, I do not see whats wrong with my code. Its not really a greedy solution, since I am going through all cases? and the test case where I am failing is unfortunately is too long to debug.